# Engine of "draw a stickman"

Tags: xamarin

I know that Games like "draw a stickam" or "wordament" uses xamarin, but are they using some game engines like monogame or cocossharp? Or there are some other engines which can I use with xamarin?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stickman was written with MonoGame.